# https://localhost:443 becomes https://localhost

Tags: https, ports

I launch a web application by `sudo PORT=443 HTTPS=true ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start`.

Then, I run `https://localhost:443/#/start` in a browser. It does open the start page, but the url becomes `https://localhost/#/start`.

Could anyone tell me why `https://localhost:443/#/start` becomes `https://localhost/#/start`?

PS: The browser is Chrome.

Comment: Because port 443 means https, and that is already in the URL.

Comment: The default https port is 443 so the port is assume to be 443 and isn't necessary.  The port is only required if you are hosting the website on a different port (but typically the web application will handle the redirect) or multiple websites on the same server (but again the web application would handle the redirection).

Answer (score 1):

HTTP default hidden port is `80`, while HTTPs is `443`.

Example:

```
http://localhost | http://localhost:80

https://localhost | https://localhost:443
```

443 is the default port for HTTPs websites.

For example,
<kbd>https://superuser.com</kbd>

Is the same as
<kbd>https://superuser.com:443</kbd>

*and*

<kbd>http://superuser.com</kbd>

Is the same as
<kbd>http://superuser.com:80</kbd>